# Moving a field of pixels inside a picture in Python with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a code, which will swap two selected rectangles inside a picture. The rectangles start at a given Y-coordinate, are 100 pixels "thick" and have the width of the whole picture.

I have two separate for loops in two separate functions right now, where I can replace those pixels, but I'm not able to combine those two loops. When I write, a nested for-loop, my code keeps freezing.

Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("Jenny-RedEyes.jpg")

def change2(y2):
    width, height = im.size
    ymin=y2
    ymax=y2+100
    xmin=0
    xmax=width
    
    for i in range(xmin, xmax):
        for j in range(ymin, ymax):
            r, g, b = im.getpixel((i,j))
            im.putpixel( (i,j), (50,50,50))

def change(y1):
    print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)
    width, height = im.size     
    ymin1=y1
    ymax1=y1+100
    xmin1=0
    xmax1=width    
    
    print (ymax1, ymin1, xmax1, xmin1)          
            
    for a in range(xmin1,xmax1):
        for b in range(ymin1, ymax1):
            r1, g1, b1 = im.getpixel((a,b))
            im.putpixel( (a,b), (1,1,1))  


change(0)
change2(166)
im.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what you mean about "combining" the two loops. Could you show the attempt that freezes? Also: try thinking about the problem step by step. How would you write code to swap a *single* pixel with a *single other* pixel? Now, what happens if you put *that* code into loops over the width and height of a rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid to say that I understand your question properly, but here's my attempt that answers your question:

> I'm trying to write a code, which will swap two selected rectangles inside a picture. The rectangles start at a given Y-coordinate, are 100 pixels "thick" and have the width of the whole picture.

Here's my approach to swap two selected rectangle from a picture:

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("Jenny-RedEyes.jpg")

width, _ = im.size
xmin=0
xmax=width

def getpixels(yaxis):
    pixels=[]
    for i in range(xmin, xmax):
        for j in range(yaxis, yaxis+100):
            r, g, b = im.getpixel((i,j))
            pixels.append((r,g,b))
    return pixels

def replacepixels(yaxis,pixels):
    index=0
    for i in range(xmin,xmax):
        for j in range(yaxis,yaxis+100):
            im.putpixel((i,j),pixels[index])
            index=index+1

def doalljob(yaxis1,yaxis2):
    firstpart=getpixels(yaxis1)
    secondpart=getpixels(yaxis2)

    replacepixels(yaxis2,firstpart)
    replacepixels(yaxis1,secondpart)    

doalljob(0,166)

im.show()
```

`getpixels` function returns rectangle pixels and `replacepixels` function replace rectangle by given `pixels`. And `doalljob` function first takes `pixels` and replaces those `pixels` to another rectangle part of image.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental technique for problems where something has to be done repeatedly:

1. Figure out exactly what "something" is.
2. Write the code to do it.
3. Write the appropriate loops for repeating that thing.

What are we trying to do? Swap pixels in the image. What does a single instance of that look like? It looks like taking *one* pair of pixels, and swapping them. For example, we could:

- Read both pixel values.
- Write the second pixel's value to the first location.
- Write the first pixel's (old) value to the second location.

Since this is a *process* that takes a few steps and can reasonably be named, we should use a *function* to wrap it up. So:

```
def swap_pixels(im, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    r1, g1, b1 = im.getpixel((x1, y1))
    r2, g2, b2 = im.getpixel((x2, y2))
    im.putpixel((x1, y1), (r2, g2, b2))
    im.putpixel((x2, y2), (r1, g1, b1))
```

Now, what loops do we need? Same as before: we want to repeat this process for a *single* rectangular region - we just iterate over "offset" positions within the width and height of the rectangle, and apply **the same** offset to **both** points. Right?

So, we'll start our ranges **at `0`**, so that we can add them to the "start points". And we'll put all of this in a function as well.

```
def swap_rectangles(im, width, height, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            swap_pixels(im, x1+i, y1+j, x2+i, y2+j)
```

See how it works? The `range`s give us offset values that we can use to find two corresponding pixels, and then we swap them. When we write this part of the code, we *don't have to think about* how the swapping works. We just think about what we want to swap.

Finally, we can call it:

```
im = Image.open("Jenny-RedEyes.jpg")
width, height = im.size
swap_rectangles(im, width, 100, 0, 0, 0, 166)
```